# How to copy home directory from one WSL installation to another

Tags: wsl2, home-directory

I have been running "Ubuntu" with WSL 1 for several months, but realized it is time to upgrade to Ubuntu-20.04 with WSL 2.  The installation itself went fine, but created a new home directory for me.  How do I copy the home directory from the old version, which is still on the machine to the new version?

Also, how can I check to make certain any software I installed (e.g. emacs) is also installed on the new version?

I'm currently trying tarring the directory under one version and untarring it under the other, but the "path names" are sometimes too long and tar refuses to write a tar file.

Attempting to simply upgrade my version from WSL1 to WSL2 produces the error message shown below:

```
 wsl --set-version ubuntu 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Exporting the distribution failed.
bsdtar: Couldn't read link data: I/O error
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: Why didn't you just update your original instance to version 2?

Comment: How to do that?  I didn't find instructions on how.  That seems like a better solution.  A pointer to a web page on how to do that will suffice...  (HOpefully)

Comment: Microsoft documentation on how you enable WSL2 also documented the process to upgrade existing instances to [version 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#step-5---set-wsl-2-as-your-default-version).  You can also upgrade your existing instance to Ubuntu 20.04 using the appropriate commands (also well documented)

Comment: The step to simply upgrade to WSL2 produces an error message that I have added to m question

 wsl --set-version ubuntu 2
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
For information on key differences with WSL 2 please visit https://aka.ms/wsl2
Exporting the distribution failed.
bsdtar: Couldn't read link data: I/O error
bsdtar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.

Comment: What would you do if it wasnt WSL?  Just tar up the stuff you want.. and copy it into the other.

Comment: if I wasn't in WSL I would do:
sudo apt update && sudo apt ugrade
do-release-update

and that doesn't work either

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I recently encountered the same issue.

I've found the best way to simply execute this in two WSL's open to the home directory of each different WSL installation

```
$ explorer.exe .
```

This brings up the current working directory of each WSL installation, and then I drag the files between them. This isn't great for permissions however, so you'll want to check they are ok (specifically key files in ~/.ssh/ etc).

If you can't figure out how to launch a different terminal for a different WSL you can also just open up windows explorer to `\\wsl$\` to see available installations and you will be able to browse to home\username in there.